# az provider register --namespace Microsoft.EventGrid silently fails

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to register a resource provider in my Azure subscription - I am "Global administrator".

If I try from the portal, I click "Register" and it spins then reports as "NotRegistered"

I've also tried:

```
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.EventGrid
```

It doesn't give any errors but remains not registered.

I've attached output from --verbose --debug

cli.knack.cli: Command arguments: ['provider', 'register', '--namespace', 'Microsoft.EventGrid', '--verbose', '--debug']
cli.knack.cli: **init** debug log:
Enable color in terminal.
cli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.PreExecute []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandParser.OnGlobalArgumentsCreate [<function CLILogging.on_global_arguments at 0x7fa32e1a8bf8>, <function OutputProducer.on_global_arguments at 0x7fa32e0dd730>, <function CLIQuery.on_global_arguments at 0x7fa32e0f5840>]
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableCreate []
cli.azure.cli.core: Modules found from index for 'provider': ['azure.cli.command_modules.resource']
cli.azure.cli.core: Loading command modules:
cli.azure.cli.core: Name                  Load Time    Groups  Commands
cli.azure.cli.core: resource                  0.016        40       186
cli.azure.cli.core: Total (1)                 0.016        40       186
cli.azure.cli.core: These extensions are not installed and will be skipped: ['azext_next']
cli.azure.cli.core: Loading extensions:
cli.azure.cli.core: Name                  Load Time    Groups  Commands  Directory
cli.azure.cli.core: ai-examples               0.122         1         1  /opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure-cli-extensions/ai-examples
cli.azure.cli.core: Total (1)                 0.122         1         1
cli.azure.cli.core: Loaded 41 groups, 187 commands.
cli.azure.cli.core: Found a match in the command table.
cli.azure.cli.core: Raw command  : provider register
cli.azure.cli.core: Command table: provider register
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableTruncate [<function AzCliLogging.init_command_file_logging at 0x7fa32dc22158>]
cli.azure.cli.core.azlogging: metadata file logging enabled - writing logs to '/home/rob/.azure/commands/2021-09-15.14-03-21.provider_register.347.log'.
az_command_data_logger: command args: provider register --namespace {} --verbose --debug
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreArgumentLoad [<function register_global_subscription_argument..add_subscription_parameter at 0x7fa32dc470d0>, <function register_global_query_examples_argument..register_query_examples at 0x7fa32db93378>]
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostArgumentLoad []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostCommandTableCreate [<function register_ids_argument..add_ids_arguments at 0x7fa32db93400>, <function register_cache_arguments..add_cache_arguments at 0x7fa32db93510>]
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnCommandTableLoaded []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreParseArgs []
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostParseArgs [<function OutputProducer.handle_output_argument at 0x7fa32e0dd7b8>, <function CLIQuery.handle_query_parameter at 0x7fa32e0f58c8>, <function register_global_query_examples_argument..handle_example_parameter at 0x7fa32db932f0>, <function register_ids_argument..parse_ids_arguments at 0x7fa32db93488>]
cli.azure.cli.core.commands.client_factory: Getting management service client client_type=ResourceManagementClient
cli.azure.cli.core.adal_authentication: AdalAuthentication.get_token invoked by Track 2 SDK with scopes=('https://management.core.windows.net//.default',)
cli.azure.cli.core._profile: Retrieving token from ADAL for resource 'https://management.core.windows.net/'
urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:50342
urllib3.connectionpool: http://localhost:50342 "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1" 200 2069
msrestazure.azure_active_directory: MSI: Retrieving a token from http://localhost:50342/oauth2/token, with payload {'resource': 'https://management.core.windows.net/'}
urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:50342
urllib3.connectionpool: http://localhost:50342 "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1" 200 2069
msrestazure.azure_active_directory: MSI: Retrieving a token from http://localhost:50342/oauth2/token, with payload {'resource': 'https://management.core.windows.net/'}
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request URL: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions//providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/register?api-version=2021-04-01'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request method: 'POST'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request headers:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Accept': 'application/json'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-client-request-id': 'af7aca98-162d-11ec-bdbe-0a580af4288b'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'CommandName': 'provider register'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'ParameterSetName': '--namespace --verbose --debug'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'User-Agent': 'AZURECLI/2.28.0 (DEB) azsdk-python-azure-mgmt-resource/19.0.0 Python/3.6.10 (Linux-5.4.0-1058-azure-x86_64-with-debian-10.2) cloud-shell/1.0'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Authorization': '*****'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request body:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: This request has no body
urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): management.azure.com:443
urllib3.connectionpool: https://management.azure.com:443 "POST /subscriptions//providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/register?api-version=2021-04-01 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Response status: 200
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Response headers:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Pragma': 'no-cache'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Expires': '-1'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-writes': '1199'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-request-id': '2750cf1e-52e5-4036-bfe2-475969efc403'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-correlation-request-id': '2750cf1e-52e5-4036-bfe2-475969efc403'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-routing-request-id': 'WESTEUROPE:20210915T140322Z:2750cf1e-52e5-4036-bfe2-475969efc403'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Date': 'Wed, 15 Sep 2021 14:03:22 GMT'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Response content:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: {"id":"/subscriptions//providers/Microsoft.EventGrid","namespace":"Microsoft.EventGrid","authorizations":[{"applicationId":"4962773b-9cdb-44cf-a8bf-237846a00ab7","roleDefinitionId":"7FE036D8-246F-48BF-A78F-AB3EE699C8F3"},{"applicationId":"823c0a78-5de0-4445-a7f5-c2f42d7dc89b"}],"resourceTypes":[{"resourceType":"locations","locations":[],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"locations/eventSubscriptions","locations":["West US 2","East US","West US","Central US","East US 2","West Central US","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","SoutheastAsia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","Norway East","West US 3"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"eventSubscriptions","locations":["West US 2","East US","West US","Central US","East US 2","West Central US","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"SupportsExtension"},{"resourceType":"topics","locations":["West US 2","East US","West US","Central US","East US 2","West Central US","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"CrossResourceGroupResourceMove, CrossSubscriptionResourceMove, SystemAssignedResourceIdentity, SupportsTags, SupportsLocation"},{"resourceType":"domains","locations":["Central US","West US 2","East US","West US","East US 2","West Central US","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2018-09-15-preview"],"capabilities":"CrossResourceGroupResourceMove, CrossSubscriptionResourceMove, SystemAssignedResourceIdentity, SupportsTags, SupportsLocation"},{"resourceType":"domains/topics","locations":["Central US","West US 2","East US","West US","East US 2","West Central US","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","CentralIndia","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2018-09-15-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"topicTypes","locations":["West US 2","East US","West US","Central US","East US 2","West Central US","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Brazil Southeast","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"operations","locations":["West US 2","East US","West US","Central US","East US 2","West Central US","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Brazil Southeast","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"locations/operationsStatus","locations":["West US 2","East US","West US","Central US","East US 2","West Central US","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"locations/operationResults","locations":["West US 2","East US","West US","Central US","East US 2","West Central US","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","CanadaEast","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"locations/topicTypes","locations":["West US 2","East US","West US","Central US","East US 2","West Central US","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"extensionTopics","locations":["West US 2","East US","West US","Central US","East US 2","West Central US","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"SupportsExtension"},{"resourceType":"operationResults","locations":[],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"operationsStatus","locations":[],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-06-01","2020-04-01-preview","2020-01-01-preview","2019-06-01","2019-02-01-preview","2019-01-01","2018-09-15-preview","2018-05-01-preview","2018-01-01","2017-09-15-preview","2017-06-15-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"systemTopics","locations":["global","West Central US","Central US","West US 2","East US","West US","East US 2","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-04-01-preview"],"capabilities":"CrossResourceGroupResourceMove, CrossSubscriptionResourceMove, SystemAssignedResourceIdentity, SupportsTags, SupportsLocation"},{"resourceType":"systemTopics/eventSubscriptions","locations":["global","West Central US","Central US","West US 2","East US","West US","East US 2","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-04-01-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"partnerRegistrations","locations":["Global"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-04-01-preview"],"capabilities":"CrossResourceGroupResourceMove, CrossSubscriptionResourceMove, SupportsTags, SupportsLocation"},{"resourceType":"partnerNamespaces","locations":["West Central US","Central US","West US 2","East US","West US","East US 2","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","SouthAfrica North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-04-01-preview"],"capabilities":"CrossResourceGroupResourceMove, CrossSubscriptionResourceMove, SupportsTags, SupportsLocation"},{"resourceType":"partnerTopics","locations":["West Central US","Central US","West US 2","East US","West US","East US 2","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-04-01-preview"],"capabilities":"CrossResourceGroupResourceMove, CrossSubscriptionResourceMove, SystemAssignedResourceIdentity, SupportsTags, SupportsLocation"},{"resourceType":"partnerTopics/eventSubscriptions","locations":["West Central US","Central US","West US 2","East US","West US","East US 2","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-04-01-preview"],"capabilities":"None"},{"resourceType":"partnerNamespaces/eventChannels","locations":["West Central US","Central US","West US 2","East US","West US","East US 2","Australia East","Australia Southeast","Australia Central","Japan East","Japan West","West Europe","North Europe","Southeast Asia","East Asia","North Central US","South Central US","Brazil South","Canada Central","Canada East","Central India","South India","West India","France Central","UK West","UK South","Korea Central","Korea South","South Africa North","UAE North","Switzerland North","Germany West Central","West US 3","Norway East"],"apiVersions":["2021-06-01-preview","2020-10-15-preview","2020-04-01-preview"],"capabilities":"None"}],"registrationState":"Registered","registrationPolicy":"RegistrationRequired"}
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnTransformResult [<function _resource_group_transform at 0x7fa32dbf3d90>, <function _x509_from_base64_to_hex_transform at 0x7fa32dbf3e18>]
cli.knack.cli: Event: CommandInvoker.OnFilterResult []
cli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.SuccessfulExecute []
cli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.PostExecute [<function AzCliLogging.deinit_cmd_metadata_logging at 0x7fa32dc22378>]
az_command_data_logger: exit code: 0
cli.**main**: Command ran in 1.414 seconds (init: 0.114, invoke: 1.300)
telemetry.save: Save telemetry record of length 3011 in cache
telemetry.check: Returns Positive.
telemetry.main: Begin creating telemetry upload process.
telemetry.process: Creating upload process: "/usr/bin/../../opt/az/bin/python3 /opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/telemetry/**init**.py /home/rob/.azure"
telemetry.process: Return from creating process
telemetry.main: Finish creating telemetry upload process.
PS /home/rob>

Comment: Try to run `az provider register` with `--verbose` and `--debug` switches. Hopefully that should give you some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came back to this today and the providers were registered